# How to reload a view in a TabBar controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I have a UITableView that I use to send an email using MFMailComposeViewController.  It displays the data correctly the first time.  If I send or cancel the email, I get a blank screen from that point forward (in other words, I can't send email again).

When I come back to the view to send an email again, it's blank, therefore the view needs to be re-loaded as it originally was.

What do I have to do to fix this?  (I'm using XCode4 with Storyboards and ARC).

Comment: How do you present the mail composer?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;  //  set delegate to notify us what's happen'in

Comment: No, I meant how do you display it? Are you pushing it onto an `UINavigationController` or present it as a model view controller or...?

Comment: Oh... [self presentModalViewController: mailer animated:TRUE];

Comment: Can you please post the code you have in `viewDidUnload`?

Comment: Are you doing anything in `view(Will|Did)Disappear` or `view(Will|Did)Appear`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misused API: When using a `UITabBarController`, `viewDidLoad` is only called once at the beginning of the load of the view. Therefore, when you put code in `viewDidLoad`, it only gets executed once. By moving that code to `viewWillAppear`, it gets loaded each time.

Comment: just FYI: 'viewDidLoad:' is always only called once in the lifetime of a viewController. (Only in the case, the view got unloaded beacause of memory issues, it will be loaded once again when needed).

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading the view on dismissal of the email, with [self.view setNeedsDisplay] straight after the email is sent or cancelled.

Edit : How about [emailView resignFirstResponder]; ?

Comment: No... that did nothing... however, I did notice this:    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  I don't have this view as "modal"... would that cause the problem?

Comment: I don't know, needsDisplay was a guess, I've always just added the subview again, like [firstview addSubview:viewIWantToReload]